# reordering terms by a "standard" order

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I want to be able to read in my files and reorder the lines according to my "standard" order below:

```
array([(1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.,  0.244  ),
       (1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., -4.29215),
       (2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.2047 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 0., -6.5627 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.,  0.7344 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., -4.0579 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.1443 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 1., -5.0526 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.7698 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 0.,  3.2056 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.7423 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 1., -3.3287 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., -3.4362 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,  0.0878 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 0., -7.2668 )],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('T', '<f8'), ('X_JTabcd', '<f8')])
```

where 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'J', and 'T' are in this specific order such that when I read in a file that is in a different order, 
 e.g.

```
array([(2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.7501 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., -3.1126 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.9984 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.5008 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 1., -5.5662 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 0.,  3.0092 ),
       (2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.6111 ),
       (1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., -4.0900),
       (1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.,  0.3772 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,  0.0098 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 0., -7.5109 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., -3.4611 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 1., -3.0982 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 0., -6.9021 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.,  0.5597 )],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('T', '<f8'), ('X_JTabcd', '<f8')])
```

it will take the form of my "standard" order and rearrange its terms to come out like:

```
array([(1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.,  0.3772 ), 
       (1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., -4.0900), 
       (2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.6111 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 0., -6.9021 ), 
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.,  0.5597 ), 
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., -3.1126 ), 
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.7501 ), 
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 1., -5.5662 ), 
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.5008 ), 
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 0.,  3.0092 ), 
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.9984 ), 
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 1., -3.0982 ), 
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., -3.4611 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,  0.0098 ), 
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 0., -7.5109 )], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('T', '<f8'), ('X_JTabcd', '<f8')])
```

and if I read in a file that has missing terms, I want it to fill in that missing line to have a 'X_JTabcd' value of 0. 
e.g. input file:

```
array([(2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., -3.9922 ),
       (2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.5902 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.8712 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,  0.0012 ),       
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 0., -7.1728 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., -4.1002 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 1., -5.8110 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 0.,  3.5501 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.5244 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 0., -7.2892 )],
dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('T', '<f8'), ('X_JTabcd', '<f8')])
```

desired outcome:

```
array([(1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.,  0.0000 ),
       (1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  0.0000),
       (2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  1.5902 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 0., -7.1728 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.,  0.0000 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 0., -4.1002 ),
       (2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.8712 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 0., 1., -5.8110 ),
       (2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 0.,  0.0000 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 1., 0.,  3.5501 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 1., -1.5244 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 1.,  0.0000 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., -3.9922 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.,  0.0012 ),
       (2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 0., -7.2892 )],
dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8'), ('J', '<f8'), ('T', '<f8'), ('X_JTabcd', '<f8')])
```

Anybody got a suggestion on how to sort the input files to my "standard" order?

Comment: To be clear: do you mean that you want to sort according to the value of the `a` field, breaking ties according to the value of the `b` field, breaking any remaining ties according to the `c` field etc.? In that case, did you try... `np.sort(myarray)`?

Comment: I want to order the terms by row, not columns. I only care about the ordering of the 'X_JTabcd' values. The `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `J`, and `T`, are only there to help with the ordering.

Comment: There aren't columns - this array is one-dimensional, and the elements are records. If you sort it, you will get them in the correct order. Filling in the missing rows is a different problem. I'm also not sure what you mean about reading in files - how are they formatted?

Comment: I have other files that are the same format as my examples above - just in different order.

Comment: So, they're Python source files, and you `import` them? Or just what?

Comment: Yes. They're text files and I import them using np.genfromtxt.

Answer (score 0):

Clarify a couple of things.

How are you reading these files?  The exact statement would help.  In particular are spelling out the `dtype`, or using the `dtype=None` option, and getting the field names from the file.  A sample of csv might help.

Once you have an array, you can 'view' it with different field order

```
arr[['a','c','b',....]]
```

That's a `view`.  You may want to `repack` it

There's a lot more about what you can do with structured arrays at

```
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html
```

Also `genfromtxt` lets you specify `usecols` as well as `dtype` and `names`.

Changing field names is possible, but requires copying values from a source array to a target array, using field names.

From a casual reading of your array displays it is hard to tell just what changes you want to make.  Maybe editing to highlight the `dtype` part.  We don't need to see all of the rows, just a couple.

Comment: I realize the way I set up my question was a little hard to follow. I'll try to be clearer next time. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Since the fields are all float, it may be simpler to load these files with default dtype, getting a 2d float array.  It's easier to reorder columns and add one.  But I don't know how you identify the column identities on the file.